# вызов метода из 2-го класса

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Класс MapsKart

```
public class MapsKart {

private GoogleMap map;
//тело программы
public void makMarkers()
{

   map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,0)));

}


}
```

Класс MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "MarkApp";
MapsKart mapsKart;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
   //вот здесь пытаюсь вывести
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
    mapsKart.makMarkers();

}

}
```

в лог. ругается на нулевой объект

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.admin.busstop.MapsKart.makMarkers()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас не инициализирован mapsKart

```
mapsKart = new MapsKart();
mapsKart.setMap(map); //Ну или каким другим образом задаем в нем map
mapsKart.makMarkers();
```